# Sending Multiple Arguments to a Command in .net repeater

Tags: c#, .net, repeater

I have a repeater that has a link button in it that i am trying to use to execute some code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="SelectCourse" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "crs_no") %>' ID="SelectCourse"> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title1")%></asp:LinkButton>
```

In the code behind I have:

```
protected void Courses_ItemCommand ( object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.CommandName == "SelectCourse" )
        {
            this.ParentPortlet.PortletViewState [ "crs_no" ] = e.CommandArgument.ToString ( );

            this.ParentPortlet.NextScreen ( "SelectDate" );
        }
    }
```

This is working fine however I cannot figure out how to use multiple arguments with this method. I want to send an additional argument so that I can set another "PortletViewState" with the second argument.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can't! unless you concatenate the arguments into a single string with a delimiter.

but i find that nasty, I use multiple hidden fields intead, that i load on the command using e.Item.FindControl

```
protected void Courses_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "SelectCourse")
    {
        HiddenField hdnCrsNo = e.Item.FindControl("hdnCrsNo") as HiddenField;
        this.ParentPortlet.PortletViewState["crs_no"] = hdnCrsNo.Value;

        this.ParentPortlet.NextScreen("SelectDate");
    }
}
```

Comment: code example in answer, hdnCrsNo is the id of the HiddenField you include in your repeater's ItemTemplate

Comment: So should I be able to add a hidden field like so: <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnsec_no" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sec_no")%>'
                            runat="server" />

Comment: yap, just make sure to update the ID on the FindControl example I provided.

Comment: on another note, you can use <%# Eval("sec_no")%> instead of <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sec_no")%> but am not sure what FX version you're using.